# Generate JSON annotation file from PNG mask

Tags: python, annotations, image-segmentation

I have been supplied with a series of image pairs to help with an image segmentation project. One image is the original RGB photo, the other is a PNG file which has masked parts of the original image. See example below.

[image: RGB of House]

[image: Alpha of house]

My image segmentation training script requires I have an annotated JSON file for each RGB file, showing the bale and coordinates of the masked. For example:

```
"label": "window",
      "points": [
        [
          48.30337078651685,
          507.9887640449438
        ],
        [
          73.02247191011236,
          510.7977528089888
        ],
        [
          71.33707865168539,
          419.7865168539326
        ],
        [
          44.93258426966292,
          423.1573033707865
        ]
      ]
```

I have 1000's of RGB and mask PNG files to use to improve my model training, but I currently don't know how to convert the PNG labels into JSON polygons.

Is there a tool out there that can help?

Alternatively, is there a method of training I can use to use these files as they are?

Comment: Some pointer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60573495/9215780

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something similar to this

```
import cv2

def get_segmentation_annotations(segmentation_mask, DEBUG=True):
    hw = segmentation_mask.shape[:2]
    segmentation_mask = segmentation_mask.reshape(hw)
    polygons = []

    for segtype in SegmentationClass.values():
        seg_type_name = proto_api.get_segmentation_type_name(segtype)
        if segtype == SegmentationClass.BACKGROUND:
            continue
        temp_img = np.zeros(hw)
        seg_class_mask_over_seg_img = np.where(segmentation_mask==segtype)
        if np.any(seg_class_mask_over_seg_img):
            temp_img[seg_class_mask_over_seg_img] = 1
            contours, _ = cv2.findContours(temp_img.astype(np.uint8), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
            if len(contours) < 1:
                continue
            has_relevant_contour = False
            for contour in contours:
                if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 2:
                    continue
                has_relevant_contour = True
                polygons.append((contour, seg_type_name))
            if DEBUG and has_relevant_contour:
                fig = plt.figure()
                fig.suptitle(seg_type_name)
                plt.imshow(temp_img)
    return polygons

def get_segmentation_dict(segmentation_mask, img_id="0", starting_annotation_indx=0, DEBUG=False):
    annotations = []
    for indx, (contour, seg_type) in enumerate(get_segmentation_annotations(segmentation_mask, DEBUG=DEBUG)):
        segmentation = contour.ravel().tolist()
        annotations.append({
            "segmentation": segmentation,
            "area": cv2.contourArea(contour),
            "image_id": img_id,
            "category_id": seg_type,
            "id": starting_annotation_indx + indx
        })
    return annotations
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but maybe a pointer.  A part of my learning I was using the instructions at https://www.highvoltagecode.com/post/edge-ai-semantic-segmentation-on-nvidia-jetson  This ends up training the model using a jpg and matching png mask if you already have the png this may off a path.
Good Luck
JC